# Ruby on Rails SQL Query Returns #<ActiveRecord::Relation:

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I built a small twitter clone in Ruby on Rails. It has a User model, a Micropost model, and a Relationships model. The Relationships model stores followed user ids and corresponding following user ids. I am trying to add a new button that makes the current user follow all other users with a matching parameter in their microposts. I have added that parameter to the micropost model. The problem is, when I query the database in the micropost model to find users with that matching parameter it returns

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:...
```

Why is it doing this?

Here is my form code that includes the button:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => current_user.matched_user), :remote => true) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Found A Matching User - Click Here To Follow Them" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the referenced matched_user definition in the user model:

```
def matched_user
Micropost.matched_with(self)
end
```

Here is the referenced matched_with method in the micropost model. I tried a few different things so I noted each error I am getting for each set of lines.

```
def self.matched_with(user)         

# matched_microposts = Micropost.find_by_parameter(:parameter)
# where("user_id IN (#{matched_microposts}) OR user_id = :user_id", :user_id => user)

# ERROR: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#create
# Couldn't find User with id=#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb59c71dc>





# matched_id = Micropost.where("parameter = ?", :parameter)
# where("user_id IN (#{matched_id}) OR user_id = :user_id", :user_id => user)

# ERROR: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Pages#home
# SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "#": SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts"
# WHERE (user_id IN (#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb5b7d3b4>) OR user_id = 101)





# matched_ids = Micropost.find_by_sql "SELECT user_id FROM microposts WHERE parameter = :parameter"
# where("user_id IN (#{matched_ids})", :user_id => user)

# ERROR: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#create
# Couldn't find User with id=#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb5a38850>

end
```

Here is my relationships controller create method:

```
def create
@user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
current_user.follow!(@user)
respond_to do |format|
format.html { redirect_to @user }
format.js
end
end
```

And finally, here is my user model follow! method:

```
def follow!(followed)
relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
end
```

Thank you very much any help you can provide. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

first of all `Model.where` returns a relation object to which you can chain other operators(another `.where` or `.order`, etc)

if you want a record to be found in db you have to explicitly close that chain with `.first`, `.last`, `.all` or even iterate over results using `.each`

second - why are you trying to directly insert results into string using `#{matched_ids}`? that will call `#to_s` on a relation object instead of properly building list of these objects to be used in a query

try this:

```
where("user_id IN (?)", matched_ids)
```